# How do I make sure that my sliding window is creating the right amount of windows?

Tags: python, text, iterator, full-text-search, sliding-window

Thanks! I modified my sliding window code code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757803/how-do-i-fix-a-sliding-window-program-that-does-not-place-data-in-all-windows), but it stills creates one less window than there should be.

If you want more info on the problem, I wrote about the initial problem there. In short, I am dealing with a large text file containing the decimal places of pi that has this format. Note that the header is all numbers and does not have a string.

I need to make a sliding window that crops the file using three arguments (window_size, step_size, and last_windowstart). last_windowstart is where the last window starts.

It works but there should be 238 windows not 237.

I know lastcounter is working right, but I'm not sure about lastwindow_start. I have tried changing its value and it is definitely part of the problem.

Xrange has to be part of the problem too

Any thoughts on sliding_window or lastwindow_start?

```
inputFileName = "sample.txt"

import itertools
import linecache

def sliding_window(window_size, step_size, lastwindow_start):
    for i in xrange(0, lastwindow_start, step_size):
        yield (i, i + window_size)

def PiCrop(window_size, step_size):

f = open(inputFileName, 'r')

first_line = f.readline().split()

Total_Pi_Digits = int(first_line[0])

lastwindow_start = Total_Pi_Digits-(Total_Pi_Digits%window_size)

lastcounter = (Total_Pi_Digits//window_size)*(window_size/step_size)

flags = [False for i in range(lastcounter)]

first_line[0] = str(window_size)
second_line = f.readline().split()
offset = int(round(float(second_line[0].strip('\n'))))
first_line = " ".join(first_line)

f. close()

with open(inputFileName, 'r') as f:
    header = f.readline()
    data = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f.readlines()]

    for counter, window in enumerate(sliding_window(window_size,step_size,lastwindow_start)):
        chunk = data[window[0]:window[1]]

        with open('PiCrop_{}.txt'.format(counter), 'w') as output:

            if (flags[counter] == False):
                flags[counter] = True

                headerline = float(linecache.getline(inputFileName, window[1]+1)) - offset
                output.write(str(window_size) + " " + str("{0:.4f}".format(headerline)) + " " + 'L' + '\n')

            for item in chunk:
                newline = str("{0:.4f}".format(float(str(item).translate(None, "[]'"))-offset))
                output.write(str(newline) + '\n')

PiCrop(1000,500)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add an exception to handle the remainder.

Say you have 99 pi_digits and you want 10 pi_digits in each file (window_size). But since there are 99 pi_digits, there can't be 10 pi_digits in each window.

There will be 10 pi_digits in the first 9 windows and 9 pi_digits in the last window.

This gives us a total of 10 windows with a step_size of 0.
Since there isn't a step_size, we need to factor that into the program.

Let's use a step_size of 5. This moves up the pair by 5 each time
The pairs are as following:

- (0, 10)
- (5, 15)
- (10, 20)
- (15, 25)
- (20, 30)
- (25, 35)
- (30, 40)
- (35, 45)
- (40, 50)
- (45, 55)
- (50, 60)
- (55, 65)
- (60, 70)
- (65, 75)
- (70, 80)
- (75, 85)
- (80, 90)
- (85, 95)
- (90,99)

Note the last pair is (90,99). This breaks the pattern.

So we add the following line 'yield (lastwindow_start, total_pi_digits)' to add the last pair, whi

```
def sliding_window(window_size, step_size, lastwindow_start,total_pi_digits):
    for i in xrange(0, lastwindow_start, step_size):
        yield (i, i + window_size)
yield (lastwindow_start, total_pi_digits)
```